# How to convert a path containing unix environment variable to an absolute path in perl?

Tags: linux

Let's say on my current shell, I have an environment variable -
A_VAR set to "/tmp/"

I am defining a perl variable as (which is using A_VAR) -

```
my $path = "${A_VAR}/this/path/file.txt";
```

I am looking for a module which provides a function to convert `$path` to `/tmp/this/path/file.txt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest just using A_VAR directly:

```
my $path = "$ENV{A_VAR}/this/path/file.txt";
```

If A_VAR may be non-absolute, that's a separate thing to handle - there are many modules that do this work, depending on how you like to interact with it. File::Spec, Path::Tiny, etc.